# Angularjs respects finally when invoked explicitly. Is this a good practice?

Tags: angularjs, q

I have a $http.post request and I understand how angular wraps the $q promises with .success and .error.

Apart from the angular docs and source code I also referred to http://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http

Here is my code:

```
$http.post(url, info).success(onSuccess).error(onError)["finally"](function() {
          return spinner.dismiss(); });
```

This works. But I am not sure if it is the right practice. Are there any situations where this can fail/throw exception? What would be a better way to do this (.then(success,error).finally)?

On further digging I see that the .error is implemented as

```
function (fn) {
    promise.then(null, function(response) {
      fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

The returned promise allows me to chain a 'finally'. This is the way angularjs has wrapped .error and .success, so chaining a .finally to the block may not be a bad practise.

Comment: Although it works, I would suggest to avoid using this approach since your code happens to become less readable. If you have some common finally demand, write your own service wrapping $http and use it when needed.

Comment: Wrapping $http for this one-off case seems over engineering IMO.